# Swift can't read the textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput after entering a newline

Tags: ios, swift, string, custom-keyboard, uiinputviewcontroller

I am typing string text on `textDocumentProxy` in a custom keyboard app. The input text includes newlines and punctuation letters, but when I try to edit the textDocumentProxy field, the `textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput` in case a newline `\n` is included, it does not return full content before input.

I place the cursor on after good morning word center , I got only good string text. The remaining `"hi folks"`, words do not return.

Here are some examples I have tried.

```
var inputText = "Hi folks,

Good morning to everyone "

var txtBeforeCursor = textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput ?? ""

print("Before Cursor text : ",txtBeforeCursor)
```

Output is:

```
Before Cursor text : Good
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.